# Setting font color on DefaultStyledDocument

Tags: java, swing, defaultstyleddocument

I know that I can set the font size on a `javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument` like this:

```
public void apply(DefaultStyledDocument document) {
    final MutableAttributeSet attributeSet = new SimpleAttributeSet();
    StyleConstants.setFontSize(attributeSet, 12);
    document.setCharacterAttributes(0, 80, attributeSet, false);
}
```

How do I set the font color?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess you use the StyleConstants.setForeground(...) method.